# JVM Terminated error exit code=13 while opening Omnet++

Tags: eclipse, jvm, ide, omnet++, exit-code

After installing Omnet++, ./configure and make, I am getting this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/bin/../ide/../samples
-jar /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/omnetpp
-name OMNeT++ IDE
--launcher.library /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 340021
-vm /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=/home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/bin/../ide/../samples
-jar /home/jayabalan/usr/omnetpp-4.6/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

I have downloaded jre 1.8 versiona nd put it in the ide folder inside the Omnet++ directory. Please help!

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I couldn't figure it out directly as I am using Omnet++ which is built on top of eclipse. I was confused about the error as it has several dependencies!